# Symfony2 My custom form field type isn't populated with data from entity

Tags: forms, symfony, custom-field-type

I created simple custom field

```
class InputWithDescriptionType extends AbstractType
{
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'description'         => '',
    ));

}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
       ->setAttribute('description', $options['description'])
   ;
}

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars['description'] = $options['description'];
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'text';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'input_with_description';
}
}
```

and added it to my form

```
$builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('about', 'input_with_description', array(
            'description' => "description",
            'label' => "label",
        ))
```

When submitting form all data is saved properly but when I try to edit entity using this form the custom fields are all empty. Where may the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product'
        ));
    }
```

Replace 'AppBundle\Entity\Product' with your entity class.

Comment: You mean I should add this to field type or form? I have it in my form class.

Comment: You need to tell the entity name to symfony, from where it will populate the data into form controls.

Comment: I have this method in my main form class and non-custom fields are populating just fine. Only the custom ones are empty. When I tried to add it to field type I got "The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AppBundle\Document\Brief, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of AppBundle\Document\Brief. "

Comment: You can refer the same type of problem being discussed here, they are recommnding to make data class null (not blank) if you have your transformation custom logic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782878/symfony2-form-entity-to-string-transformer-issue